# Recursive Union Type and List

Tags: f#

I'm starting with F# and I read about recursive Union Types on https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-in-60-seconds//

Given the example from the link

```ml
type Employee =
  | Worker of Person
  | Manager of Employee list
```

How can I create a value of type `Manager` and assign a List of Workers to it?

I can create a value of type `Worker` like this:

```ml
let john = {First = "John"; Last="Doe"}
let worker = Worker john
```

But I don't know how to create a value `jane` of type `Manager` having `john` assigned as an item of the `Empoyee` list:

```ml
let jane =  { First="Jane"; Last="Doe" }
let manager = Manager [worker]
```

This works, but I can't assign `First` and `Last` from `jane` to `manager`.

Is manager meant to have no `First` / `Last` at all in this example?

How would I have to change the type definition for Manager to have both a list of `Employee`?

In addition it also looks like `Manager` doesn't have a member `employees` I can access after creating a value of type `Manager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that type definition, a manager cannot have first/last name. The type definition does not include anything like that.

To make `Manager` work similarly to `Worker` in this regard, just give it a `Person` value:

```
type Employee = Worker of Person | Manager of Person * Employee list
```

Then you can create a manager Jane:

```
let manager = Manager ({ First = "Jane"; Last = "Doe" }, [worker])
```

---

As for a member `employees`, there are several things to say.

First, stay away from members. F# is functional-first. Functions are better than members (for reasons that I'm not going to go into here). Have a function:

```
let employees emp = 
    match emp with
    | Manager (_, emps) -> emps
    | Worker _ -> ???  // what to return if the employee turned out to be worker?
```

And right away you can see a difficulty: when the employee is a `Manager`, sure, we can return their employees. But what if it's a `Worker`? What to return then?

One reasonable suggestion would be to return an empty list, because, after all, a `Worker` doesn't have any employees working for them, right?

```
let employees emp = 
    match emp with
    | Manager (_, emps) -> emps
    | Worker _ -> []
```

Another possibility would be to return an `Option`. Which approach is "correct" depends on what you're going to do with the result, so only you can answer that.

But if you absolutely insist on having a member (and please, *please* carefully think about why you need it), you can definitely add a member to your type like this:

```
type Employee = Worker of Person | Manager of Person * Employee list
    with
        member this.employees =
          match this with
          | Manager (_, emps) -> emps
          | Worker _ -> []
```

Comment: An instance member is effectively a function which takes the instance, but with slightly different ergonomics. Usually cleaner than a static member, or the equivalent method of putting a function inside a module with the same name. Since you can convert from one to the other easily, it doesn't matter very much which you do, and the best approach can depend on future usage.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie in fact, the two approaches are not mutually exclusive, and you can do both (as does F# itself, where you can use for example `List.length xs` or `xs.Length`).